# Grep particular word from a line using grep/awk commands

Tags: command-line, mount, text-processing

I Tried this cmd:

```
# mount | grep -E '\s/dev/shm\s' | awk  -F "(" '{print $NF}'
```

Expectations:

```
rw,nosuid,nodev,seclabel
```

What I get this:

```
rw,nosuid,nodev,seclabel)
```

and I also tried this one:

```
mount | grep -E '\s/dev/shm\s' | awk  -F "(" '{print $NF}' | cut -c -24
```

```
rw,nosuid,nodev,seclabel
```

I can get the exact wordm but in default there is any one word was not there it will not work so i need to remove this character `)` in the end, anyone know about this? Teach me to solve this.

Comment: Did you try: `mount | grep -E '\s/dev/shm\s' | awk -F "[()]" '{print $2}'` ?

Comment: thanks for the reply! It works fine

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing that the output of your `mount | grep` command is like this:

```
$ mount | grep -E '\s/dev/shm\s'
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,inode64)
```

So what you want (again, I am guessing here) is the text between the parentheses on lines containing `/dev/shm`. If so, try:

```
$ mount | grep -oP '\s/dev/shm\s.+\(\K[^)]+'
rw,nosuid,nodev,inode64
```

The `-o` option tells `grep` to only print the matching part of the line and the `-P` enables PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) which give us `\K` for "ignore everything matched up to this point". So the regular expression will look for `/dev/shm` surrounded by whitespace, then as many characters as possible until an opening parenthesis (`.+\(`). Everything up to here is now ignored because of the `\K` and then we just match the longest stretch of non`-)` characters (`[^)]+`).

---

If you really need to use `awk` for some reason, there's no need for `grep`:

```
$ mount | awk -F'[()]' '/\s\/dev\/shm\s/{print $(NF-1)}'
rw,nosuid,nodev,inode64
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works fine.

Answer (score 2):

`findmnt` is usually used to find and show details like device names, mounts, or file system types.

```
findmnt -n --target /dev/shm --output=options
```

Active *mounts* are found in `/proc/mounts` and has a fixed number of columns, which makes it easy to parse:

```
while read -r _ a _ b _; do
    [[ $a = /dev/shm ]] && echo $b
done < /proc/mounts
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It works fine

Comment: @lee, If one of the answers here solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](//askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the checkmark on the left. That is the best way to express your thanks on the Stack Exchange sites.